# How can I connect to NWWS-OI in Python?

Tags: python, weather, noaa

I am trying to build a program that interfaces with the NWWS Open Interface, or NWWS-OI for short. This is a service that provides NWS products over XMPP. I have an account (you have to request it), but how can I use it in Python?

I looked up "nwws-oi python", and I found https://github.com/jbuitt/nwws-python-client/. However, this will not work, as the script is intended for Linux systems, but I need to run this on a Windows system! I couldn't find any other GitHub repositories when I looked up "nwws-oi python", so how can I do this? (I ideally want a solution using slixmpp.)

Edit: Already tried porting it to Windows! Whenever I try to run it, I get this error:

```
INFO     Using SSL version: TLS
ERROR    Connection error.
ERROR    <TagSet object, tags 0:32:16> not in asn1Spec: <OctetString schema object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:4>, encoding iso-8859-1>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 1492, in _process
    if not self.__read_xml():
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 1564, in __read_xml
    self.__spawn_event(xml)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 1632, in __spawn_event
    handler.prerun(stanza_copy)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\handler\callback.py", line 64, in prerun
    self.run(payload, True)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\handler\callback.py", line 76, in run
    self._pointer(payload)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\features\feature_starttls\starttls.py", line 64, in _handle_starttls_proceed
    if self.xmpp.start_tls():
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 889, in start_tls
    cert.verify(self._expected_server_name, self._der_cert)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\cert.py", line 134, in verify
    cert_names = extract_names(raw_cert)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\cert.py", line 72, in extract_names
    value = decoder.decode(extension.getComponentByName('extnValue'),
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 1618, in __call__
    raise error.PyAsn1Error(
pyasn1.error.PyAsn1Error: <TagSet object, tags 0:32:16> not in asn1Spec: <OctetString schema object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:4>, encoding iso-8859-1>
INFO     Waiting for </stream:stream> from server
INFO     Negotiating TLS
INFO     Using SSL version: TLS
ERROR    Connection error.
ERROR    <TagSet object, tags 0:32:16> not in asn1Spec: <OctetString schema object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:4>, encoding iso-8859-1>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 1492, in _process
    if not self.__read_xml():
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 1564, in __read_xml
    self.__spawn_event(xml)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 1632, in __spawn_event
    handler.prerun(stanza_copy)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\handler\callback.py", line 64, in prerun
    self.run(payload, True)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\handler\callback.py", line 76, in run
    self._pointer(payload)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\features\feature_starttls\starttls.py", line 64, in _handle_starttls_proceed
    if self.xmpp.start_tls():
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 889, in start_tls
    cert.verify(self._expected_server_name, self._der_cert)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\cert.py", line 134, in verify
    cert_names = extract_names(raw_cert)
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\cert.py", line 72, in extract_names
    value = decoder.decode(extension.getComponentByName('extnValue'),
  File "C:\Users\thest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 1618, in __call__
    raise error.PyAsn1Error(
pyasn1.error.PyAsn1Error: <TagSet object, tags 0:32:16> not in asn1Spec: <OctetString schema object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:4>, encoding iso-8859-1>
INFO     Waiting for </stream:stream> from server
```

Edit 2: This is what happens when it runs without pyasn1 and pyasn1_modules:

```
INFO     Using SSL version: TLS
WARNING  Could not find pyasn1 and pyasn1_modules. SSL certificate COULD NOT BE VERIFIED.
INFO     JID set to: [username removed]@nwws-oi.weather.gov/6fus3pafx6
WARNING  Could not find pyasn1 and pyasn1_modules. SSL certificate expiration COULD NOT BE VERIFIED.
WARNING  Use of send mask waiters is deprecated.
```

Then it just hangs after this!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe try WSL?  That repo you pointed to is a very minimal wrapper, surely it wouldn't take much to port it to Windows anyway!

Comment: @SamMason Here is my porting attempt: [https://github.com/TechyTommy3/nwws-python-client](https://github.com/TechyTommy3/nwws-python-client) I also had to run it on Python 3.9, because SleekXMPP is incompatible with Python 3.10 and above. Is there something I missed?

Comment: I don't know the libraries, but discarding output is generally a bad idea in my experience.  Have you tried just leaving the output going to the terminal and making sure there aren't any issues reported?  A quick look into the code of sleekxmpp suggests that it only uses ASN1 for certificate expiry validation.  If you don't care about security you could presumably just bypass that bit of the code, e.g. search for HAVE_PYASN1 in the repo.

Comment: @SamMason First of all, about the piping, I removed it. Second, it can run without pyasn1, but it gets stuck!

Comment: "Use of send mask waiters is deprecated." sounds useful, maybe have a look into where the code uses that and fix that next...  this tends to be how working with software goes, you keep following the trail until you get the result you want!

Comment: @SamMason It doesn't really mean anything. When I looked it up, I found [https://github.com/errbotio/errbot/issues/291](https://github.com/errbotio/errbot/issues/291), which says that this error is related to the `wait=True` on line 86. When I run it on `wait=False`, it's the same result, just not with the error!